# dataclasses from multi-row/column csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a csv file, and assign the values to different dataclasses. After this, I have to conduct various analysis of the dataclasses, such as mean, mode, median, etc.

The issue I am having is importing them in such a way that I can use them later. I have the following code written:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List
import csv
from csv import DictReader

@dataclass
class Grades:
    class_course: str
    class_grades: int

@dataclass
class Student:
    name: str
    grades: List[Grades] = field(default_factory=list)

def create_student_db():
    s = Student([],[])
    courses = []
    with open("Sample Data/Sample2.csv") as read_obj:       # pass the file object to DictReader() to get the DictReader object
        csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
        csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj, delimiter = ",")  # get column names from a csv file
        column_names = csv_dict_reader.fieldnames
        for col in column_names:
            if col == "Student Name":
                continue
            else:
                courses.append(col)                         # Create list of column names

        for row in csv_reader:                              # For each row in the csv file
            n = row[0]                                      # The first value is the name
            s.name.append(n)                                # Append the name to the name of the student class
            i = 0                                           # For iteration through the values on the row
            while i < len(row)-1:                           # While i is less than the length of the row
                g = Grades(courses[i], row[i + 1])          # Set values in the Grades class to the Course name, and the row value + 1
                s.grades.append(g)                          # Append the values for the Grades to the Grades in Student
                i += 1

    return s

a = create_student_db()

print(a)
```

The input file looks like this (csv format):

```
Student Name,Course_1,Course_2,Course_3,Course_4
Johnny Rotten,10,20,20,40
Sid Vicious,90,50,30,10
Lars Larsson,90,10,30,60
John Jameson,90,90,90,90
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Student(name=['Johnny Rotten', 'Sid Vicious', 'Lars Larsson', 'John
Jameson'], grades=[Grades(class_course='Course_1', class_grades='10'),
Grades(class_course='Course_2', class_grades='20'),
Grades(class_course='Course_3', class_grades='20'),
Grades(class_course='Course_4', class_grades='40'),
Grades(class_course='Course_1', class_grades='90'),
Grades(class_course='Course_2', class_grades='50'),
Grades(class_course='Course_3', class_grades='30'),
Grades(class_course='Course_4', class_grades='10'),
Grades(class_course='Course_1', class_grades='90'),
Grades(class_course='Course_2', class_grades='10'),
Grades(class_course='Course_3', class_grades='30'),
Grades(class_course='Course_4', class_grades='60'),
Grades(class_course='Course_1', class_grades='90'),
Grades(class_course='Course_2', class_grades='90'),
Grades(class_course='Course_3', class_grades='90'),
Grades(class_course='Course_4', class_grades='90')])
```

Obviously, this is for an academic exercise, but I am having problems following the lectures.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the dataclasses done so that it is meaningfull, and I can pull out values like individual student means, modes, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. What is confusing you is that you are    placing the name of the students and the grades inside one student object which doesn't make sense.

- Have a list of `Student`, in which each `Student` will have a `name` and a list of
  `grades`.
- I would suggest changing the class name from `Grade` to `Course` with
  attributes `name` and `grade`. The attribute name from `grades` to
  `courses` in Student. It's easier to understand that way. A student is registered in courses which they will have been given
  grades.
- Also, remember to convert the grades to `int`. That way
  you can make calculations later.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List
import csv
from csv import DictReader

@dataclass
class Course:
    name: str
    grade: int

@dataclass
class Student:
    name: str
    courses: List[Course] = field(default_factory=list)

def create_student_db():
    students = []
    courses = []
    with open("Sample Data/Sample2.csv") as read_obj:       # pass the file object to DictReader() to get the DictReader object
        csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
        csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj, delimiter = ",")  # get column names from a csv file
        column_names = csv_dict_reader.fieldnames
        for col in column_names:
            if col == "Student Name":
                continue
            else:
                courses.append(col)                         # Create list of column names

        for row in csv_reader:                              # For each row in the csv file
            n = row[0]                                      # The first value is the name
            s = Student(name=n)                               # Append the name to the name of the student class
            students.append(s)
            i = 0                                           # For iteration through the values on the row
            while i < len(row)-1:                           # While i is less than the length of the row
                g = Course(courses[i], int(row[i + 1]))          # Set values in the Grades class to the Course name, and the row value + 1
                s.courses.append(g)                          # Append the values for the Grades to the Grades in Student
                i += 1

    return students

students = create_student_db()

print(students)
```

Output:

```
[Student(name='Johnny Rotten', courses=[Course(name='Course_1', grade=10), Course(name='Course_2', grade=20), Course(name='Course_3', grade=20), Course(name='Course_4', grade=40)]),
 Student(name='Sid Vicious', courses=[Course(name='Course_1', grade=90), Course(name='Course_2', grade=50), Course(name='Course_3', grade=30), Course(name='Course_4', grade=10)]),
 Student(name='Lars Larsson', courses=[Course(name='Course_1', grade=90), Course(name='Course_2', grade=10), Course(name='Course_3', grade=30), Course(name='Course_4', grade=60)]),
 Student(name='John Jameson', courses=[Course(name='Course_1', grade=90), Course(name='Course_2', grade=90), Course(name='Course_3', grade=90), Course(name='Course_4', grade=90)])]
```

As @martineau suggested also, you can use the functions from the `statitiscs` module.

Example:

If you want to know the mean of a student's grades considering all of his/her courses.

```
import statistics as st
st.mean(map(lambda c: c.grade, students[0].courses))
```

output:

```
22.5
```

Comment: @Mauricio, thank you for the approach, and the ideas about the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

It was unclear to me what the format of your student database was supposed to be, so I just made it a list of `Student` instances — which I think would be very easy to use in conjunction with the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module in completing the rest of the exercise.

Another alternative would be a dictionary of students mapping to a sub-dictionaries of course names and associated grades.

```
import csv
from csv import DictReader
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pprint import pprint, pp
from typing import List


INPUT_FILEPATH = "Sample2.csv"

@dataclass
class Grade:
    class_course: str
    class_grade: int

@dataclass
class Student:
    name: str
    grades: List[Grade] = field(default_factory=list)

def create_studentDB():

    students = []
    with open(INPUT_FILEPATH, newline='') as read_obj:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj, delimiter=',')
        fieldnames = next(csv_reader)  # Header row.
        courses = fieldnames[1:]
        for row in csv_reader:
            name = row[0]
            grades = [Grade(course,  int(grade)) for course, grade in zip(courses, row[1:])]
            students.append(Student(name, grades))

    return students

studentDB = create_studentDB()
pprint(studentDB)
```

Results:

```
[Student(name='Johnny Rotten', grades=[Grade(class_course='Course_1', class_grade=10), Grade(class_course='Course_2', class_grade=20), Grade(class_course='Course_3', class_grade=20), Grade(class_course='Course_4', class_grade=40)]),
 Student(name='Sid Vicious', grades=[Grade(class_course='Course_1', class_grade=90), Grade(class_course='Course_2', class_grade=50), Grade(class_course='Course_3', class_grade=30), Grade(class_course='Course_4', class_grade=10)]),
 Student(name='Lars Larsson', grades=[Grade(class_course='Course_1', class_grade=90), Grade(class_course='Course_2', class_grade=10), Grade(class_course='Course_3', class_grade=30), Grade(class_course='Course_4', class_grade=60)]),
 Student(name='John Jameson', grades=[Grade(class_course='Course_1', class_grade=90), Grade(class_course='Course_2', class_grade=90), Grade(class_course='Course_3', class_grade=90), Grade(class_course='Course_4', class_grade=90)])]
```

Comment: thank you for the help. Very much appreciated.